# How to concatenate two dataframes based on the particular columns?

Tags: python, join, merge, append, concatenation

There are 2 dataframes which have different columns.
I'm trying to concatenate them based on the first 3 columns.

```
   a b c X
1  H A 8 1
2  M D 3 2
3  H A 9 3
4  L C 9 4

   a b c Y
1  H A 8 4
2  M D 3 3
3  H A 9 2
4  L C 9 2
```

It's the expected result:

```
   a b c X Y
1  H A 8 1 4
2  M D 3 2 3
3  H A 9 3 2
4  L C 9 4 2
```

I can't find a efficient way to concatenate them!!

Comment: What is the inefficient method that you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) should working nice:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a','b','c'])
```

If need dynamically use first 3 columns:

```
print (df1.columns[:3].tolist())
['a', 'b', 'c']

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df1.columns[:3].tolist())
```

---

```
print (df)
   a  b  c  X  Y
0  H  A  8  1  4
1  M  D  3  2  3
2  H  A  9  3  2
3  L  C  9  4  2
```

But if possible first 3 columns are different in both `DataFrame`s and need join by them:

```
cols = df1.columns[:3].tolist()
df2 = df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.columns[:3], cols)))
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

- if output order doesn't matter,
- a,b,c are same for each row,
- X & Y are distinct for each row.

> > > ls1 = [set(['H','A',8,1]), set(['H','A',8,4])] 
> > >       ls1 = set().union(*ls1) 
> > >       print ls1 
> > >       set(['A', 1, 4, 8, 'H'])

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print (new_df)

output:-       a  b  c  X  Y
            0  H  A  8  1  4
            1  M  D  3  2  3
            2  H  A  9  3  2
            3  L  C  9  4  2
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.